Hour and Minutes Timestamp in Pine Script
I tried to create candle's "hour and minutes" timestamp in Tradingview pine script. I could create hour timestamp but not minutes next to it. Can someone fix this problem?
//Time Stamp
inTime = (hour(time, syminfo.timezone))
Table_Def = table.new(position = position.middle_right, columns = 30, rows = 1, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.black, border_width = 1)
table.cell(Table_Def, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Time", text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_left)
table.cell(Table_Def, column = 1, row = 0, text = str.tostring(inTime[29]), text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_right)

@Jeremy Caney Thank you for carrying out the correction. It missed my attention while posting.

// Time Stamp
inTime = str.format_time(time, "HH:mm", syminfo.timezone)
Table_Def = table.new(position = position.middle_right, columns = 30, rows = 1, frame_color = color.black, frame_width = 1, border_color = color.black, border_width = 1)
table.cell(Table_Def, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Time", text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_left)
table.cell(Table_Def, column = 29, row = 0, text = str.tostring(inTime[1]), text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_right)
table.cell(Table_Def, column = 30, row = 0, text = str.tostring(inTime[0]), text_color = color.black, text_size = size.auto, text_halign = text.align_right)
and so on...
I welcome any other format/syntax to fulfill the requirement as an alternative.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
